# Atomic reads/writes of 64 bit values in 32 bit mode with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, atomic

Is there any intrinsic or other way in gcc of persuading it to do 64 bit reads and writes atomically rather than as 2 32 bit writes? (At least in one or two places).

Currently I'm having to do `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_fetch_and_add` to get it to do the reads/writes atomically, but the CPUs in question have 64 bit fetch and store instructions.

I'd prefer not to write loads of inline assembler (presumably one for each CPU we have to support) with #ifs spread around.

I'm currently using gcc 4.4.6 and am unlikely to get that upgraded in the short term.

Comment: the simple answer is no, because of several reasons, least of which is creating special instructions for the target CPU.  The complex answer is what are your target CPUs and if gcc has special flags for them?  You either have to do what you're doing or create the appropriate function CPU specific  `asm { }` wrappers

Comment: err. they created special instructions for __sync_fetch_and_add.

Comment: oh right you are using Itanium CPUs ... silly me...  well they do support `long long` as the type (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) and should generate atomic code which should do the trick for 64-bit values

Comment: but those are the bodges I'm using. I'd like just a simple fetch and store. fetch and add 0 for a read seems overkill

Comment: if the downvoter could explain why?

Comment: How are you compiling your program, and for what target, exactly?

Comment: -march=i686 -m32 although we also want to use this for powerpc and sparc architectures.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "long long" the memory access won't be atomic.

However maybe a "double" memory access may be atomic when using a 64-bit CPU (even in a 32 bit program):

```
union {
    long long ll;
    double d;
} u;

u.ll = my_value;
*(double *)&my_long_long_variable = u.d;
```

However if the number "my_value" in this example will result in a "signalling NaN" value for u.d then you may get an exception when doing this this way!

Maybe the compiler will not even use FPU registers for this code. In this case the memory access won't be atomic and assembler programming will be needed. You'll definitely need to use either FPU registers or XMM/MMX/... registers for atomic 64-bit accesses.